# Find index where a sub-tensor does not equal to a given tensor in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor, for example,

```py
a = [[15,30,0,2], [-1,-1,-1,-1], [10, 20, 40, 60], [-1,-1,-1,-1]]
```

which has the shape `(4,4)`.
How can I find the index where a specific sub-tensor

```py
[-1,-1,-1,-1]
```

that doesn't appear using PyTorch. The expected output I want to get is

```py
[0,2]
```

Comment: But why [0,2]? , I think it is [1,3] which are the indices of rows.

Comment: From your answer, you are looking for the indices of tensors which NOT equal to the subtensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare the elements for each row of the tensor using `torch.any()`, and then use `.nonzero()` and `.flatten()` to generate the indices:

```
torch.any(a != torch.Tensor([-1, -1, -1, -1]), axis=1).nonzero().flatten()
```

---

For example,

```py
import torch

a = torch.Tensor([[15,30,0,2], [-1,-1,-1,-1], [10, 20, 40, 60], [-1,-1,-1,-1]])
result = torch.any(a != torch.Tensor([-1, -1, -1, -1]), axis=1).nonzero().flatten()
print(result)
```

outputs:

```py
tensor([0, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `where` or `nonzero`:

```
a = torch.Tensor([[15,30,0,2], [-1,-1,-1,-1], [10, 20, 40, 60], [-1,-1,-1,-1]])

b = torch.Tensor([-1,-1,-1,-1])

result = torch.where(a != b)[0].unique()

result = torch.nonzero(a != b, as_tuple=True)[0].unique()

print(result)
```